# Would the compiler (or the JVM) know to optimise this piece of code? how do I check?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

Suppose I have this class

```
Util
{
    public static void doSomething()
    {
         if (FLAG) foo();
         else bar();
    }

    public static void foo() { /* do something */ }
    public static void bar() { /* do something else */ }

    public static final boolean FLAG = computeFlag();
    private static boolean computeFlag() { /* do some computation during init time*/ }
}
```

`FLAG` is obviously never going to change.
And suppose `Util.doSomething()` is used *A LOT* (and in many critical places, where performance does matter).
Would the Java compiler, or the JVM, be smart enough to cache the body of `doSomething` so that the code would not have to re-evaluate `FLAG` or have to execute the branch instruction all over again?

How do I check this?

Thanks

Comment: The compiler, no. The JVM, maybe.

Comment: The branch predictor of a CPU is going to tear that if a new one with its awesomeness, if the value never changes.

Comment: OOps, my apologies, I didn't mean the compiler. I meant the JVM, yes.

Comment: I did change it. (It could be the compiler, too, if maybe some compiler is smart enough to statically evaluate the body of `computeFlag` and see that the value is known at compile-time, hence the value of `FLAG` is also known at the compile time... :D )

Comment: It's final at runtime, not compile time. If computeFlag could theoretically be affected by anything at all determined at runtime, the compiler cannot determine the value at compile time. If not, you should just figure it out and assign it directly.

Answer (score 5):

That is likely to depend on the JVM you use. For the Oracle Hotspot JVM, you can inspect the generated machine code using

```
java -server -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly your.MainClass
```

provided you have the necessary native library in the library path (the [documentation](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) mentions where you can get such binaries).

Running the class:

```
public class DecompileTest {

    public static void doSomething() {
        if (FLAG)
            foo();
        else
            bar();
    }

    static int fooCount;

    public static void foo() {
        fooCount++;
    }

    public static void bar() {
        fooCount--;
    }

    public static final boolean FLAG = computeFlag();

    private static boolean computeFlag() {
        System.out.println("Shall I set the flag? (y/n)");
        try {
            return System.in.read() == 'y';
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            doSomething();
        }
        System.out.println(fooCount);
    }   
}
```

with

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)
```

on my Intel cpu produces a lengthy disassabmly, of which the relevant part reads:

```
Decoding compiled method 0x009ca408:
Code:
[Entry Point]
[Verified Entry Point]
[Constants]
  # {method} 'doSomething' '()V' in 'stackoverflow/DecompileTest'
  #           [sp+0x10]  (sp of caller)
  0x009ca500: sub    $0xc,%esp
  0x009ca506: mov    %ebp,0x8(%esp)     ;*synchronization entry
                                        ; - stackoverflow.DecompileTest::doSomething@-1 (line 8)
  0x009ca50a: mov    $0x295dc208,%ebx   ;   {oop(a 'java/lang/Class' = 'stackoverflow/DecompileTest')}
  0x009ca50f: incl   0x70(%ebx)         ;*putstatic fooCount
                                        ; - stackoverflow.DecompileTest::foo@5 (line 17)
                                        ; - stackoverflow.DecompileTest::doSomething@6 (line 9)
  0x009ca512: add    $0x8,%esp
  0x009ca515: pop    %ebp
  0x009ca516: test   %eax,0x950000      ;   {poll_return}
  0x009ca51c: ret    
  0x009ca51d: hlt    
  0x009ca51e: hlt    
  0x009ca51f: hlt    
[Exception Handler]
[Stub Code]
  0x009ca520: jmp    0x009c78c0         ;   {no_reloc}
[Deopt Handler Code]
  0x009ca525: push   $0x9ca525          ;   {section_word}
  0x009ca52a: jmp    0x009ae280         ;   {runtime_call}
  0x009ca52f: hlt
```

That is, both the test of `FLAG` and the invocation of `bar()` have been eliminated as dead code, and the method body of `foo` inlined.

Comment: +1 (I would've given you +100 if it'd let me!) for the docs on how to get the disassambly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this kind of code is an easy target for HotSpot's dead code elimination. Even if `FLAG` may change, HotSpot will determine by profiling that, in the actual execution, it is always the same, and eliminate the untaken branch.

Reference: [PerformanceTacticIndex](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTacticIndex).

Comment: Yes, the JVM can inline flag like this into the code.  In fact it will do this for non-final flags as well. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html

Comment: "Even if `FLAG` may change, HotSpot will ... eliminate the untaken branch": I don't quite agree. Being a speculative optimization, the generated machine code must test the condition at least once so it can deoptimize if needed, the generated maching code will therefore still contain a branch instruction. Indeed, if I remove final, and run the test code in my answer, `FLAG` is tested, and branched if false. In fact, even the call to `bar()` is still part of the generated machine code if `FLAG` is not final.